# how to extract patches from background image of an image without bounding box area in python?

Tags: python, image-recognition

I have an image of person with bounding box values, after removing boundingbox from image i want patches of backgroung image with out overlapping with bounding box

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately this a really broad question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question in order to increase the probability of getting the answer you're searching for.